# Why is my native android code in Flutter showing errors?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am testing platform specific coding with Flutter. I opened the android folder in Android Studio, wrote my code and it shows no errors. I then moved back to Flutter which is underlining in red the Rs in the code below. However, the app is working fine. I am wondering why an error is showing and what I can do to remove these red lines. I would be grateful for pointers.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyTileService extends TileService {

private final int STATE_ON = 1;
private final int STATE_OFF = 0;
private int toggleState = STATE_ON;


@Override
public void onTileAdded() {
    System.out.println("onTileAdded");
}

@Override
public void onTileRemoved() {
    System.out.println("onTileRemoved");
}

@Override
public void onStartListening() {
    System.out.println("onStartListening");
}

@Override
public void onStopListening() {
    System.out.println("onStopListening");
}

@Override
public void onClick() {
    System.out.println("onClick state = " + Integer.toString(getQsTile().getState()));
    Icon icon;
    if (toggleState == STATE_ON) {
        toggleState = STATE_OFF;
        icon = Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_spa_black_24dp);
        System.out.println("OFF");
    } else {
        toggleState = STATE_ON;
        icon = Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp);
        System.out.println("ON");
    }
    getQsTile().setIcon(icon);
    getQsTile().updateTile();
}
```

}

I tried cleaning the android project, uninstalling and reinstalling Flutter and Dart plugins, checking flutter doctor.

Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Often the Rs underlined in red are lint errors due to an invalid XML layout. Did you make some changes on some layout in your  `./android` project?

Comment: No, in fact there is no Layout folder there. I only added the service to the manifest and added my drawables.

Comment: Sorry, but. Are you opening the java code inside the flutter project, not opening the android project inside ./android with AS? Ain't it? I guess this the problem. If you open the android project with AS you don't have Rs in red. Right?

Comment: In this case, the lint in java code still has this issue. I've got the same R.<red_resource_folder>.resource_id

Comment: No I don't have the problem when I open/edit the project in AS. It's just that it is showing as red in Flutter. Please see the screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to configure SDK versions in File > Project Structure. If you expand the directory you'll see more details which files contains what errors.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer doing a `flutter clean` and reopen the project cleans the lint error. But If I open a java file from the flutter project structure I get the errors again. Like OP.

Comment: So it's a Flutter bug?

Comment: Don't know. I've already have the SDK Version configured in Project Structure (opening the android project). Let's see what's @GünterZöchbauer say.

Comment: @user9480972 Which version of AS are you using? I've got AS 3.3-rc2. But maybe the lint actually doesn't support R build variables inside a flutter project.

Comment: I'm on the 3.2.1 version.

Comment: I guess I've found it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2262

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Flutter projects are not Gradle-based Android projects so a number of
>   features provided by Android Studio are not available to Flutter
>   programmers.

This still is a Flutter Plugin.

Is documented here:

> [image]

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2262

And you can track it here:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2243

It seems that the first item is check, so it's only a metter of time to wait this milestone to be released.

Comment: f***. I have created several pulgins with great headache!!!!  Thank you!